# Question about JTextField and text format with numbers?

Tags: java, swing, formatting

I writing an application using Swing. My application has a text box and what I want to do is this: when user enters a number in that text field, if the number is in the thousands, then it is automatically appended a comma in the number.
For example, if user enters 1000, then it should be automatically changed to 1,000, or 1,000,000 or so.

Does anyone give me some ideas, please?

Comment: do something in the event listener? which part do you think is difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) classes.
See an example here; http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html

**Update:**

Example:

```
NumberFormat numberFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String formattedNumber = numberFormatter.format(10000000);

JTextField numberTextField = new JTextField();

numberTextField.setText(formattedNumber);
```

Comment: @Mudassir: @SamG: Can we show numbers in textFields this way? It just format numbers. isn't it?

Comment: @mudassir, a Formatted Text Field is a more appropriate answer for handling this in a GUI.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Yes we can show numbers in TextFields this way. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Mudassor: OP wants to format the number while the user typing in textField. Not like this. I know this way of doing. But this is not OP is asking as per I understand his question. But OP has accepted your answer so enjoy rep points. ;-)

Comment: @Harry: I was unaware of FormattedTextFields thats why I suggested it, your way is of course best suited.

Comment: @Mudassir: Wish OP thinks the same. :-)

Comment: @Harry: Sorry Harry, I can't uncheck that green mark. :-( But of course I can give you a +1.

Answer (score 4):

Try [formattedTextFields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Also [one more example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/234.html). May be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at group seperators in [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) .