# How to format the content of a textfield while typing

Tags: java, user-interface, text, dynamic, formatting

How can I format the content of a text field **while the user is typing**. Specifically, I want to add thousand separators to numbers.

(What to do in case of invalid/non-numeric input?  Ideally, the formatting would simply not be applied. But it would also be an acceptable solution to me to prevent invalid input in the first place - if there is a good way to do that!)

I've searched for a solution of this problem for a long time and tried lots of examples, but none of the existing answers (e.g. [Question about JTextField and text format with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498109/question-about-jtextfield-and-text-format-with-numbers)) are satisfying.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want to format while user type or just after the lost focus event?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem yourself instead of searching for a ready-made solution?

Comment: while the user is typing

Comment: In fact I have invested several hours trying to find a solution myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

Java's controls don't do this very well by default. I recommend using something like `ImprovedFormattedTextField`, which is documented very well in this post:

[Is there any way to accept only numeric values in a JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313390/is-there-any-way-to-accept-only-numeric-values-in-a-jtextfield/13424140#13424140)

Your question is not exactly a duplicate, but you should be able to adapt the class to work as you expect. The background will turn red if the number is not formatted correctly.

Comment: My question is not primarily about preventing invalid input. I'm interested in formatting (adding thousand separators). I think this cannot be done using an `ImprovedFormattedTextField`. In the example they use a property change listener to change some external component or an attribute. However, changing the text itself would cause an infinite recursion